# Kivy, saving data into a file

Tags: python, kivy

I have a kivy program which generates some images and i want it to be saved into a file on device from which users can access it

How can i implement this .??

•approach

-creating a file on installation, to which all the generated pictures can be saved(is this step same for all os.?)

-here assuming `image1` as some image generated, save it into the file on clicking the save button

Code

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory 

kv='''

BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    
                        
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        
        Button:
            size_hint:None,None 
            text:"save"
            on_press:
                app.save()      
                              

'''

#image to be saved 
image1="img.png"

class MyApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
    
    def save(self):   
        #?

        
MyApp().run()
```

Please do suggest a better approach if im wrong ,
at the end i just want the pictures to be saved into a file to be accessed later

Comment: How about writing the image-file into a file as binaries.

Comment: Can you just implement that in code.?

Comment: Have a look at the module [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html).